# Google Analytics: What would happens in two domain but not using _setDomainName?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two different domain site under same UA id without setDomainName. But for some reason, I cannot modify my code.What would happen if I didn't add _setDomainName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not setting a _setDomainName method, it takes on it's default value which is "auto", which will attempt to resolve the domain name based on the `document.domain` DOM property.

More information here - [tracking code domains and directories](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName).